# iOS - Size Classes and UICollectionView header/footer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, size-classes

I'm trying to set a different Height value for the `UICollectionViewReusableHeader` for each **Size Classes** but the **height constraint** won't work on it, can't even set it. If I change the actual `Height` property, it changes for all size classes.

All I can do is just return a height value inside `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:`

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    return iPadHeight
} else {
    return iPhoneHeight
}
```

But I need to view how does it looks in design-time, in the storyboard; so this isn't really a solution.

How can I do this?